# routes.rb, how set a different primary key for the paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a model like Thread (id, uuid) uuid being a uniquely generated identifier. I want to change the default routes:

```
edit_thread GET    /threads/:id/edit(.:format)                        {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"threads"}
thread GET    /threads/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"show", :controller=>"threads"}
PUT    /threads/:id(.:format)                             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"threads"}
```

To not use :id but to user :uuid --- How is this made possible in Rails/routes.rb?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, you want to make sure instead of the `:id` field, Rails uses the `:uuid` field in the routes.

This is quite easy to accomplish, inside your model overrule the `to_param` method:

```
def Thread
  def to_param
    uuid
  end
end
```

and inside your controller, you will have to write something like:

```
thread = Thread.find_by_uuid(params[:id])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

`:id` can be changed to whatever you like.  Your `params` hash gets populated by the name you choose in your routes, so if you changed it to `:uuid` you would just need to change your controllers accordingly (`o = Model.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])`)

Comment: Thanks but what I don't get is how to change it in my routes? Do I need to do a bunch of matches? I was thinking rails would have a more elegant setting for this... thxs

Comment: @AnApprentice: Sorry, I didn't realize you meant you wanted to change the :`id` param in the resource routes.  I don't think this is possible (you're breaking out of the rails convention here).  A similar question was asked before: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810385/how-to-rename-the-default-identifier-param-id-in-rails-map-resources).